# Can an instance be garbage collected when its member being exposed to outside world

Tags: java

Take the following case

```
// class Toy {
//     public Object b = new Object();
// }

Toy toy = new Toy();
Object theB = toy.b;
toy = null;

// Can toy instance be garbage collected right now?
```

I thought maybe `toy` cannot be garbage collected, as `theB` is currently referring to `toy.b`, and variable `b` cannot live without `toy` (As `b` is an instance member variable of `toy`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The *short* answer

Yes, it can, since there are no *strong references* to the instance of `Toy`. Think about it: how could you ever refer back to the original `Toy` instance? Impossible, isn't it? Therefore, it is indeed *garbage*, and will be collected.

For more information on *reachability* and *types of references* in Java (ie, what are *strong references*, *weak references*, etc, and how do these kinds of references interact with the Garbage Collector), take a look at the [excellent documentation of the package java.lang.ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).

---

### The *more complete, things-are-not-so-simple* answer

To extend a little bit the discussion, and to be absolutely precise, I can think of at least one situation in which the instance of `Toy` can never be collected even after your `toy = null`, were the code of the class `Toy` different.

If the constructor of the `Toy` class adds a reference to the newly created instance in some kind of global variable (or, in more precise terms, if the object is strongly reachable from a GC root). For example:

```
public class Toy {
  private static final List<Toy> myToys = new ArrayList<>();
  public Toy() { myToyw.add(this); }
}
```

If this is the case, then when you do `toy = null` in your code, still the instance cannot be GCed simply because there's still a way to reach it (through *strong references*), namely `Toy.myToys.get(0)`.

However, this is just for completeness. **I strongly advise *against* this type of code**, since it will certainly bring lots of headaches, including, but not limited to, strange memory leaks (ie, the instance cannot be GCed) and problems with multithreading (ie, you published a reference to an instance before its constructor returned, then another thread might see the object as *partially initialized*, ie, possibly in an inconsistent state).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `toy` can be garbage collected if nobody refers to it.  Once `b` is of type `Object` it refers only to its own `Class` object and nothing else, so `toy` is not referred by `b`.